# rspec test for sorting not working the way I expect it to. What's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my rspec test:

```
RSpec.describe "DisplayLinks", :type => :request do
  describe "GET links_path" do
    it "should have a list of links sorted by popularity order" do
      link1 = create(:link, clicks: 50)
      link2 = create(:link, clicks: 75)
      link3 = create(:link, clicks: 100)

      visit root_path

      within "div.all-links li:nth-child(1)" do
        expect(page).to have_content(link3.short_url)
      end

      within "div.all-links li:nth-child(2)" do
        expect(page).to have_content(link2.short_url)
      end

      within "div.all-links li:nth-child(3)" do
        expect(page).to have_content(link1.short_url)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<div class="all-links">
  <% @links.each do |link| %>
    <li>
      <%= link.short_url %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So link3 should always be on the top of the page. But, if I change the number after nth-child to 2 for the first test, it still passes. So I think I'm getting false positives. What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Index starts at 0 so nth_child(2) is really the third value.

Comment: I thought capybara indexing actually started at 1